# HTML Empty Tag Conventions

Tags: html, conventions

I was just wondering about a random misc. convention.
If you for some reason have an empty div, would you do

```
<div></div>
```

or would you do

```
<div />
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are self-closing tags valid in HTML5?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558119/are-self-closing-tags-valid-in-html5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latter is not valid markup, a `div` element cannot close itself like `img` or `br`

The reason is that a div is considered a non-void element. This means it is meant to have content, even if you leave it empty.

[Here is a list of elements which can be void, or self closing](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#void-element)

Comment: `<div />` (and `<div/>`) is valid in XHTML, just not recommended when compatibility with legacy HTML processors is an issue (like on web pages served as text/html).